# Auto compiling a dependent project without having a dependency on it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compilation, dependencies, spring.net, dependency-management

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC with extensive usage of Spring.net.

I have lots of services implemented in different assemblies. The purpose of using Spring and abstract interfaces is to **decouple** the application from the implementation of services. For example, the Data Access Layer is currently implemented by NHibernate, but the solution is designed to allow this to change.

So I have defined lots of Spring objects from foreign assemblies e.g.

```
<object id="RepositoryFactory" type="Org.Zighinetto.MyApp.NHibernateBasedRepositoryFactory, Org.Zighinetto.MyApp,NHibernate" />
```

As we all know, this works as soon as `Org.Zighinetto.MyApp.NHibernate.dll` example assembly either

- Is in GAC
- Is in `bin` directory

As of today, in order to allow quick debugging by hitting F5, I have set a dependency from the main project to all projects it depends on. As we all know, Spring is designed to allow us to **cut** the dependency between projects, but in this case I use dependencies only to tell Visual Studio to compile and deploy the DLL automatically, otherwise I would have to copy the right DLLs every time I want to debug my project.

The question is straightforward: given that I want to compile, at least in Release mode, my DLLs **without** unneeded dependencies, how can I make sure that Visual Studio, when I hit F5, automatically compile and deploys all of the Spring-required DLLs (which can be hardcoded by **me** somewhere, e.g. in a post-compile script) into bin directory?

In the `Org.Zighinetto.MyApp` example above, I want that once `Org.Zighinetto.MyApp.dll` gets compiled, VS compiles and deploy also `Org.Zighinetto.MyApp.NHibernate.dll` without having an explicit reference from `.MyApp` to `.NHibernate`

Answer (score 0):

The dependency in you project file does not make the resulting assembly in any way dependent on these referenced files. You can safely have the dependencies there during development and compile your project.

The resulting output will still work when you swap out the assemblies that contain the implementation.